# Вызов python-скрипта в PHP

Tags: php, python

Перечитал все, что доступно на эту тему здесь и на других ресурсах, но проблема упорно не хочет решаться. Я пытаюсь вызвать `Python` скрипт из `PHP`, перепробовал и system(), и popen(), но у меня ничего не выводится, либо пустота, либо единица. У меня есть подозрения, что я из самого скрипта не правильно вывожу. Я тестировал и писал его на пк, и все результаты выводил с помощью `print()`. Уточню, что скрипт просто обрабатывает `.csv` файл лежащий рядом с ним и выводит результат в виде одного единственного числа. Прикладываю код:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

# read data
data = pd.read_csv("/home/d/drewmaksim/drewmaksim.tmp/main.csv",     sep=';').dropna(axis=1, how='all')

# normalize data
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(data.drop('Пользователь', 1))

# clustering
n_clusters = 3
km = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)

# fit & predict clusters
data['cluster'] = km.fit_predict(X)

# results - we should have 3 clusters: [0,1,2]
#print(data)
print(data.ix[0, 'cluster'].item())
```

Вызов в php делал так:

```
$tested = system('python /home/d/drewmaksim/drewmaksim.tmp/script.py', $retval);
```

А затем просто выводил эти две переменные с помощью `echo()`

Comment: Просто в консоли команда `python /home/d/drewmaksim/drewmaksim.tmp/script.py` работает-то?

Comment: @andreymal, Да, выводит ту самую необходимую цифру

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php в целом ответ тут, вам нужно указать куда идёт вывод

Comment: @DmitriiBelikov, полностью повторил инструкции из той темы. Указал окружение в первой строке скрипта, выдал права. Скрипт прекрасно работает при вызове его из терминала, но на самой веб-страницы на месте вывода переменной - пустота

Comment: Вы выводите обе переменные? $tested и $retval

Comment: @DmitriiBelikov, да, в одной переменной получается пустота, а в другой всегда единица. Все другие методы предлагаемый (типа shell_exec), приводят разве что к тому, что вместо единицы выводится NULL. Уже совсем не знаю, что делать. Перепробовал все =(

Comment: @DmitriiBelikov, методом тыка я выяснил, что скрипт состоящий только из одной строчки: `print(5)`, прекрасно вывел результат на странице сайта, но как только я добавляю в файл строки `import ... from ...`, вывод сразу опять становится пустым. Почему-то именно при вызове из PHP есть какая-то проблема с импортом библиотек, мне кажется я напал на след решения проблемы, но пока не знаю как это исправить

Comment: @DmitriiBelikov, углубление в вопрос приводит к еще более не обычным результатам. Запуск PHP файла из командной строки на сервере `php index.php` выводит в командную строку html составляющую и потом выводит результат работы скрипта. То сть php файл из терминала может вывести результат, а на сайте - нет. Как такое возможно?

Comment: Я протестировал на простом python скрипте - отработало. Похоже проблема действительно с import. Тут нашёл подобную https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable проблему. Нужно веб-серверу указать PATH, правда там Apache